# Firebase Cloud: Retrieve all values of the filed 'expireDate' from document

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve value in 'expireDate' from products which belongs for current user (User has a reference to a product). I'm using Flutter and Firebase Cloud - Database.

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
String product = 'exampleId';

    Firestore.instance
        .collection('users/${user.uid}/products')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
        print(document.data['idProduct'].path);
        print(document.data['idProduct']);
      });
    });
```

[image: as shownbelow]
Program returns: 'Instance of 'DocumentReference'
I expect '2020-05-02'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading a document with a field that is a `DocumentReference` does not automatically load the linked document. You'll need to load the reference document explicitly, and then look up the `expireDate` field that you're looking for.

So something like

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('users/${user.uid}/products')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((snapshot) {
  snapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
    Document product = await document.data['idProduct'].get();
    print(product.data['expireDate']);
  });
});
```